# Is it possible to detect file/data transfer via usb?

Tags: android, usb, file-transfer, detect

I want to detect the file/data transfer via USB from android device to PC or vise versa. I am able to detect the USB device connected to my android device.

1) How does the file transfer application work in android?

2) Is it possible to detect the file transfer?

Comment: Where do you want to detect file transfer ? I mean suppose you are transferring file `f1` to PC from device, now , do you want to detect that file is being transferred in the PC or in the  android device itself ?

Comment: I want to detect file transferring in my android device (both,  file transferring  from my device as well as to my device(android application)).

Comment: How do you feel about using `TrafficStats` ? The API is very simple, and simply gives you the total bytes received/sent for the particular UID, so i guess you need to find out the UID for your file transfer process and feed it to that. The documentation can be found here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Comment: I used android's default file transfer application.So i don't know how it works.How can i find the UID of this default application?

Comment: See the official documentation for help  on this . I think you can get the desired UID using `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` .

Comment: Ok,I have a doubt - whether the TrafficStats class is using for network packets? Then how it can detect the file transfer between device and pc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32813/discussion-between-the-dark-knight-and-asha-soman)

Comment: I was very excited with this conversation, but when I searched about it I found the phrase "may not be available on all platforms", but I don't know how well supported is this API in general.